# sequelize.sync({ force: true }) sometimes fails to set up database correctly

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, jestjs

I'm trying to set up test fixture with Sequelize and PostgreSQL. However, the tests I wrote sometimes pass, and sometimes fail. The errors range from `SequelizeDatabaseError: type "participants_id_seq" already exists` to `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error` to `SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "participants" does not exist`, which leads me to believe that either I've set up the await incorrectly, or I've set up the sync incorrectly. I've tried using async/await, and I've also tried setting up Promises with callbacks without any luck.

Before each test, I call `sync({ force: true })`, like so

```
const { sequelize, participants: Participants } = require('../../models');

const existingUserCredentials = {
  teamName: 'TeamName',
  firstName: 'FirstName',
  lastName: 'LastName',
  email: 'helloworld@helloworld.com',
  password: 'helloworld',
};

const Fixture = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    await Participants.create(existingUserCredentials);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
};

module.exports = {
  Fixture
};
```

I'm then calling this in my test cases like so:

```
describe('POST /login', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await Fixture();
  });

  it('throws unauthorized when user does not exist', async () => {
    const { body, status } = await request(app)
      .post('/api/login')
      .send({
        email: 'someemail@helloworld.com',
        password: 'hunter123',
      });

    expect(body).toEqual({
      message: messages.INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS,
    });
    expect(status).toEqual(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  });
});
```

This test will pass some of the time, and fail the rest of the time with different errors.

My model looks like this:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Participant = sequelize.define('participants', {
    teamName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      set(password) {
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
        this.setDataValue('password', hash);
      },
    },
  });

  Participant.verifyPassword = (password, hash) =>
    bcrypt.compareSync(password, hash);

  return Participant;
};
```

and my migration looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.createTable('participants', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      teamName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      },
    }),
  down: (queryInterface) => queryInterface.dropTable('participants'),
};
```

Am I setting this up properly so I can have a clean database for each test? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

### **Update**

I figured it out. Turns out that Jest runs the test cases in parallel, so the test database was being used at the same time by multiple test cases. The real solution is to run the test cases sequentially by adding the `--runInBand` flag to the test command

```
// package.json
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --runInBand"
    }
    ...
}
```

However, this slows down the time it takes to run your test cases. A better solution would probably be to mock your database, rather than using an actual test database. There's a few out there, such as [sequelize-mock](https://github.com/BlinkUX/sequelize-mock) and [sequelize-mocking](https://github.com/rochejul/sequelize-mocking).

---

So, I wasn't able to figure this out with PostgreSQL. Instead, I switched my Sequelize configuration to use SQLite for my testing and it worked. Here's my config

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.PGUSER,
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    host: process.env.PGHOST || '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    operatorsAliases: false,
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.SQLITEUSER,
    password: process.env.SQLITEPASSWORD,
    database: process.env.SQLITEDATABASE,
    host: process.env.PGHOST || '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    operatorsAliases: false,
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.PGUSER,
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PGPRODDATABASE,
    host: process.env.PGHOST || '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    logging: false,
  },
};
```

I'm going to leave this question open though since I don't really think this is a good solution